# How to have a navigation view load in multiple activities without bugs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio, android-navigationview

I created a navigation view (Note: the newer navigation view, not a older navigation drawer which is setup differently) followed the guide found [here](http://www.androidsphere.com/how-to-implement-navigation-view-using-android-design-library/). I set it to open a new activity, were I just repeated the code again but changed the class and intent statements to reflect the current activity. (changed main activity extends to `activity2` extends,  etc) but when I do that the text view in main activity shows up in `activity2` also and ignores the `textview` in `activity2`.

so how exactly can I set this up to have the navigation view be displayed in all my activities without copying code dozens of times and each activity having there own `textview`? also i am a novice android programmer so saying "supposed to use a fragment" or something similar, I need code examples to actually understand what I need to do (again, please don't refer me to navigation drawer samples as this is set up differently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use simple scheme - one `Activity`, many `Fragments`.

For example - you can create new project in *Android studio* with `Navigation Drawer Activity` (although it says "Navigation Drawer" in the new versions of *Android studio* activity will be created with `NavigationView`) - it will create one `MainActivity` for you.

For supporting `Fragment`s scheme, you need special container on your `Activity` for content of this fragments. Let's add `FrameLayout` into `layout/content_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note, that I created `FrameLayout` with `content_frame` id - we will use it later.

Then, for example, create two blank fragments - `BlankFragment1` and `BlankFragment2`.

And now look on code in `MainActivity`, but rather on `onNavigationItemSelected` method. By default, it looks like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Each `if` statement helps us to distinguish the menu items in the navigation view. Let's change this code to go away to`BlankFragment1` by clicking on `R.id.nav_camara` and go away to `BlankFragment2` by clicking on `R.id.nav_gallery`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    Fragment fragment;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_camara:
            fragment = BlankFragment1.newInstance("param1", "param2");
            break;

        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            fragment = BlankFragment2.newInstance("param3", "param4");
            break;

        default:
            fragment = BlankFragment1.newInstance("param1", "param2");
    }

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And launch the app. Now, you can change your fragments by clicking on this two icons (camera and gallery). Hope it helps you.

Comment: okay i did that and got rid of the few issues causing red i created when I did it. now when i try to select a option within the app it crashes and i get info.test.MainActivity@31bd4c23 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: Please, provide me your code. I think, you used illegal class for fragments and Activity. You should use `AppCompactActivity` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` classes.

Comment: the problem was i needed to add the newIstance and related information to tell the switch statement to correctly load the fragment. I only had oncreateview to inflate the xml, and nothing else in my fragments.